# Replacing every alternate new line with a tab delimiter - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace every alternate new line character(\n) by tab delimiter (\t) in javascript and I am not able to get any pointers as to how to do so. 
As Strings are immutable, replacing each time would be space consuming. So the below one is the present case :

```
 Node\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\nNode\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\n172.22.1.91\t30.2987\t30.5486\n172.22.1.91\t30.2987\t30.5486\n
```

Expected :

```
 Node\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\tNode\t MB-s (rec) \tMB-s (sent)\n172.22.1.91\t30.2987\t30.5486\t172.22.1.91\t30.2987\t30.5486\n
```

Any inputs/pointers are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Input and output are the same?!

Comment: Yeah except that i am trying to change space delimiter alternately with a tab

Comment: Now I got, you want to replace every second `\n`

Comment: @ppasler Yes, but if you observe. After every three values we get a new line. Instead I want a new line after 6 values.